# Rest API batch response status

Tags: http-status-codes, restful-architecture

Suppose there is `POST /inteview/:id/invite` route.
Parameters are email addresses:

```
{ 'emails': ['foo@test.com', 'bar@test.com'] }
```

Response should indicate that some addresses are successfully invited some not. For example:

```
  [ {
      "email": "foo@test.com",
      "status": "already invited"
    },
    {
      "email": "foo@test.com",
      "status": "already invited"
    }
  ]
```

Which status to return for partial success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Response's HTTP Status Code should be `200 OK`, since you are getting the expected server's response.

Whether an email is invited or not, is not an actual error.

Comment: If all supplied emails are not in valid format (for example doesn't contain `@` sign) then I should expect from server something other than 200 status. How else to indicate to client that something is not ok?

Comment: @ИванБишевац If the client sent a request with invalid emails, then the response header should be: `400 Bad Request`.

Comment: If the request is valid, and the response contains expected information, then I don't see why not to use `200 OK`.